# What is the expected number of vertex pairs that are able to communicate with each other in cycle C4?

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory, network-flow, network

Consider the cycle graph C4 Assume that the edges of the cycle fail independently with probability q  What is the expected number of vertex pairs that are able to communicate with each other (that are in the same component) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an idea
If the graph is not labeled then these cases appear with their vertices pair count
1. No edge failed.  ${4 \choose 2}$
2. One edge failed. ${3 \choose 2}$
3. Two edges failed. Two subcases if edges are consecutive then ${3 \choose 2}$ or if alternate then ${2 \choose 2} + {2 \choose 2}$
4. Three edges failed.  ${2 \choose 2}$
5. All edges failed. ${0 \choose 2}$

Now, P(case 1) = $(1-q)^4$
Similarly, P(case 2) = $q(1-q)^3$
P(case 3) = $q^2(1-q)^2$
P(case 4) = $q^3(1-q)$
P(case 5) = $q^4$

I guess you can follow up from here.

Comment: Thank you @wild_fox I got it :)